# Allow any decimal numer in a RadMaskedNumericInput

Tags: wpf, telerik

How do I have to set the properties of the `RadMaskedNumericInput` control so that:

1. the user can enter any decimal number with any precision, with or without a decimal separator, positive or negative
2. no mask placeholders or mask literals are visible (no `_` and ideally the decimal separator only visible when the user actually entered one)

Comment: why not `RadNumericUpDown`? spin buttons can be hidden

Comment: Because we also want to be able to specify a format string (like `"#.##"` or `"E02"`) from external configuration that overrides the default behavior mentioned above. Can that be done? I don't see a `FormatString` property in `RadNumericUpDown`.

Comment: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radnumericupdown/features/formatting

Comment: Yeah, that's not quite the same as specifying a format string.